# How to save session of audio file in sqlite databade, iphone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have made a drum app in iphone. When i play drum record the sound of that after finishing play i want to save session which i played. How it possible...?? Please someone help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i store audio file in sqlite..??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213485/how-can-i-store-audio-file-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the `BLOB` data type.