# How can i store audio file in sqlite..?

Tags: iphone

I want to save recorded file and after that i want to save in sqlite database. How it possible?
Give me some proper guideline on that..
Ayn suggestion welcomes...

Comment: You've posted this same question several times before. This is a sure sway to get people to ignore you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing audio file data inside SQLITE, save the files into your file-system (like inside Documents directory) & save the file names into your SQLITE database. Refer to this SO question - [Upload video into SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004374/upload-video-in-sqlite-in-iphone/4004481#4004481)